# Is this a juvenile Middle Spotted Woodpecker?

Tags: species-identification

Place: Vienna, Austria
Time: October, 8th, 2023; morning
Behaviour: Likely eating from bark
[image]

From apps and pictures, I quickly gained confidence in this being a specimen of the Middle Spotted Woodpecker. It might be my ineptitude in perceiving size over distance, but I remember this specimen as smaller than the 20cm minimum size stated by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_spotted_woodpecker).

Is it perhaps a juvenile?

Comment: From a search i looks like the juvenile has weaker coloration. Size is notoriously hard to do without reference to something of known size nearby, so I would guess (and it is nothing more than a guess) adult.